# Custom xml attribute to a @layout reference

Tags: android, xml, android-custom-view

I would like to make a custom view with own xml attributes. I would like to specify a header layout that will be inflated in my custom xml view, something like this:

```
<com.example.MyCustomWidget
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/my_header"
   />
```

Is that possible and how to i get the layout resource from `TypedArray`?

So at the end I would like to do something like this:

```
class MyCustomWidget extends FrameLayout { 


public ProfileTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ProfileTabLayout);

    int headerLayout = a.getLayout(R.styleable.MyCustomView_headerLayout, 0); // There is no such method

   a.recycle();

   LayoutInflater.from(context)
        .inflate(headerLayout, this, true);

  }

}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="MyCustomWidget">
    <attr name="headerLayout" format="reference" />
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: please mention that on which custom view(ListView, TextView, anyLayout) you would like to perform @layout/header....
and elaborate your question..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr

Comment: maybe my question is unclear. I have updated my question and have added a code sample. @pskink I know how to declare custom xml attributes. My question is, is it possible to reference layout resources?

Comment: sure,  the format is reference

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First you have to make your custom field. Yo do this by adding code below to  `res/values/attrs.xml`

```
<declare-styleable name="MyCustomView">
    <attr name="headerLayout" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Then in your custom view you can get this value in constructor

```
public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    ...
    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.MyCustomView,
            defStyle, 0
    );

    try {
        int headerLayout = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyCustomView_headerLayout, 0);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
    ...
}
```

From here on you can inflate `headerLayout` with `LayoutInflater`

Comment: ah,  `a.getResourceId()` is what I was looking for. Thanks!