# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, kotlin

I'm currently facing an issue in my app, I've looked and tried many solutions, but I was unable to find any that actually works.

I have an activity that contains a list of custom components. This components are android CardView elements wrapped in a LinearLayout.

Each of this card components contains a Relative layout which is empty by default.

When calling the component in the activity XML file, I add the custom attribute `app:partLayout="@layout/choice_access_part"`. This attribute is processed in my component code. After that, I inflate the layout passed in reference in partLayout attribute add I try to add it to the RelativeLayout in my component.

```
val inflatedLayout: View = inflater.inflate(partLayout, selectionContainer, false)
selectionContainer.addView(inflatedLayout)
```

I have no problem compiling the application and running it until I reach this part of the code and get the error : `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class`

Component code

```
class MultipleChoiceCard(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : CardView(context, attrs) {

    val title: TextView
    val nonMandatoryText: TextView
    val selectionContainer: RelativeLayout

    init {
        val inflater: LayoutInflater = context?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.component_multiple_choice, this)

        // Getting elements in XML
        title = find(R.id.multiple_choice_title)
        nonMandatoryText = find(R.id.non_mandatory_text)
        selectionContainer = find(R.id.selection_container)

        // Extract value from XML
        val a = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MultipleChoiceCard, 0, 0)
        val titleValue = a.getString(R.styleable.MultipleChoiceCard_title)
        val nonMandatoryTextValue = a.getString(R.styleable.MultipleChoiceCard_nonMandatoryText) ?: ""
        val colorValue = a.getInt(R.styleable.MultipleChoiceCard_cardColor, R.color.user_deep_orange)
        val partLayout = a.getInt(R.styleable.MultipleChoiceCard_partLayout, R.layout.choice_rythm_part)

        // Applying the XML values to the wanted elements
        title.text = titleValue
        title.setTextColor(colorValue)
        // Set the non mandatory text visible if the value is not an empty string
        if(nonMandatoryTextValue != ""){
            nonMandatoryText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            nonMandatoryText.text = nonMandatoryTextValue
        }

        val inflatedLayout: View = inflater.inflate(partLayout, selectionContainer, false)
        selectionContainer.addView(inflatedLayout)

        a?.recycle()

    }

}
```

Component XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/rythm_card"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#2d292a">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/multiple_choice_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/user_deep_orange"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold">
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/non_mandatory_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/multiple_choice_title"
                android:textColor="#8c8f91"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
            </TextView>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/non_mandatory_text"
                android:id="@+id/selection_container">

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout passed as attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/non_mandatory_text"
        android:id="@+id/rythm_radio_group">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Libre"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:buttonTint="@color/user_deep_orange"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Toutes les 10 secondes"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:buttonTint="@color/user_deep_orange"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Toutes les 30 secondes"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:buttonTint="@color/user_deep_orange"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Toutes les minutes"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:buttonTint="@color/user_deep_orange">

        </RadioButton>

    </RadioGroup>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: put xml of this class

Comment: Can you share the .xml file? Especially line #32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching, I found the solution, and it was just a silly mistake.

The line         `val partLayout = a.getInt(R.styleable.MultipleChoiceCard_partLayout, R.layout.choice_rythm_part)` must get a resourceId and not an int, so the solution is to replace `getInt` by `getResourceId`.

The code should look like that.

```
val partLayout = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MultipleChoiceCard_partLayout, R.layout.choice_rythm_part)
```

I found the solution on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303979/custom-xml-attribute-to-a-layout-reference).